# Looping through another table and using values as variables for SELECT query

Tags: sql-server, loops

Sample data from the Delays Table is shown below:

```
+----------+-------------+
| Customer | DaysDelayed |
+----------+-------------+
|   698125 |          13 |
|   698126 |          31 |
|   698127 |           2 |
|   698128 |          11 |
|   698129 |           5 |
|   698130 |           4 |
|   698131 |          42 |
|   698132 |          29 |
|   698133 |          29 |
+----------+-------------+
```

The output desired is:

```
+------------+-------+
|   Range    | Count |
+------------+-------+
| 0-7 days   |     3 |
| 8-20 days  |     2 |
| 21-30 days |     2 |
| 31-45 days |     2 |
+------------+-------+
```

For getting the output I have written 4 queries:

```
SELECT '0-7 days', Count(*) 
FROM Delays 
WHERE DaysDelayed between 0 AND 7

SELECT '8-20 days', Count(*) 
FROM Delays 
WHERE DaysDelayed between 8 AND 20
```

and so on (the values for the label and the WHERE condition changing in each query).

The day ranges change from time to time and also the number of ranges can increase/decrease.

From a maintainability perspective, I want to store the Range values in a table as follows:

```
+---------+------------+----------+----------+
| RangeID | RangeName  | LowerEnd | UpperEnd |
+---------+------------+----------+----------+
|       1 | 0-7 days   |        0 |        7 |
|       2 | 8-20 days  |        8 |       20 |
|       3 | 21-30 days |       21 |       30 |
|       4 | 31-45 days |       31 |       45 |
+---------+------------+----------+----------+
```

and loop through this table with one SELECT query (instead of 4 queries at present).

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like

```
SELECT  RangeName,
        COUNT(d.Customer) Cnt
FROM    Ranges r LEFT JOIN
        Delays d    ON  d.DaysDelayed BETWEEN r.LowerEnd AND r.UpperEnd
GROUP BY RangeName
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7cdb2/2)

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNION` operator. It merges rows of any number of given tables

Here is the documentation:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html